# Xamarin : Unable to save a sms programmatically in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am coding in xamarin android using c# and am trying to restore sms to a phone from an existing file. I have fetched all the sms and have put them in a list ready to be saved. Now the problem is when I try to save it I get a message that sms saved but in my original messaging app I don't see the newly added sms. I have used below line of code in my function :

#### My first try

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.InterfaceConsts.Body, "Hello folks");
values.Put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.InterfaceConsts.Address, "6879890");
// values.Put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.InterfaceConsts.Type, 0);
values.Put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.InterfaceConsts.Read, 1);
values.Put(Telephony.Sms.Conversations.InterfaceConsts.Date, "1513071781");
Application.Context.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Insert(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.ContentUri, values);
```

#### My second attempt to do the same

```
var context = Application.Context.ApplicationContext;
var values = new ContentValues();
values.Put("address", "+9868665567");
values.Put("body", "Added via Xamarin");
values.Put("read", false);
values.Put("date", "1513071781");

try
{
    context.ContentResolver.Insert(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.ContentUri, values);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "SMS saved ! ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "SMS not saved ! "+ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Always I get the success message and never get an error but I can never see the reflected changes

Comment: Starting with KitKat (4.4, API level 19), your app cannot write to the SMS Provider unless it is the currently selected default messaging app. Attempts to do so by non-default apps will just fail silently.

Comment: @MikeM. so i have to make my app a default app temporarily to achieve this ? Thanks I will have to research this; will get back to this if I am able to do this

Comment: Yep. The requirements for your app to be eligible to be selected as a default are given on this blog page: [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html). There's also a section at the very end titled "Advice for SMS backup & restore apps" that has some handy tips for setting yours and switching back.

Comment: @Mike , hello , I can't get this line to work when I am trying to change the default app to my app in xamarin code : 
Intent intent =new Intent(this, Telephony.Sms.Intents.ActionChangeDefault); Any suggestions ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a misprint. You don't need a `Context` in that `Intent` constructor; just the action string. Remove the first argument, `this`.

Comment: I tried using this but even then it's not accepting

Comment: Uh, dunno. I'm not very familiar with Xamarin syntax. Seems like it should just be `new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ActionChangeDefault)`. What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Cannot convert string to type

Comment: I don't know what that means, 'cause there's definitely a constructor that takes only a `String`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/Android.Content.Intent.Intent/p/System.String/. You might try `Intent intent = new Intent();`, `intent.SetAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ActionChangeDefault);`.

Comment: [Take a look this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

Comment: @Mike your last suggestion worked perfectly thank you very much;I will post an answer to this myself.@joe I am following that very set of instructions...thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of @mike here , I have resolved the problem and can now add sms.
here is the final code :

```
        private void SMS_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = Application.Context.ApplicationContext;
        String defaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.GetDefaultSmsPackage(context);
//Add this to make your app default
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ActionChangeDefault);
        intent.PutExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ExtraPackageName, context.PackageName);
        StartActivity(intent);

//Save the message
        var values = new ContentValues();
        values.Put("address", "+982323855");
        values.Put("body", "Added via Xamarin");
        values.Put("read", false);
        values.Put("date", "1513071781");
        context.ContentResolver.Insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.ContentUri, values);

        Toast.MakeText(this, "Message added : ", ToastLength.Long).Show();

//Add this to revert the default app to what it previously was.
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ActionChangeDefault);
        intent.PutExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ExtraPackageName, defaultSmsApp);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```